# Python, Youtube-video-downloader-merger Can i inproove this script run faster?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube

I created script which one downloading video and sound from Youtube, and after that merging sound and video with ffmpeg, i wondering is another way to make same result but in faster way?  Because this script takes about 7 min ~ depends on Video quality and duration. My code bellow:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import sys
import ffmpeg
import os


class Downloader(YouTube):

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = YouTube(link)
        self.hq = []
        self.best_video = []
        self.best_sound = []


    def stream_objects(self):
        q = [self.hq.append(x) for x in self.link.streams.all()]
        self.best_video.append(str(self.hq[1]).split()[1].split('\"')[1])
        self.best_sound.append(str(self.hq[-1]).split()[1].split('\"')[1])
        return self.best_video, self.best_sound

    def downloady(self):
        vid = self.link.streams.get_by_itag(str(self.best_video).strip("['']"))
        audio = self.link.streams.get_by_itag(str(self.best_sound).strip("['']"))
        self.vid_title = (f"{vid.title}"+".mp4")

        vid.download(filename='video')
        audio.download(filename='audio')
        print('Downloaded, Now Starting Merge \n\n\n\n\n')
        print(f'{self.vid_title}'+'\n')

    def merge(self):
        ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg.input('video.mp4'), ffmpeg.input('audio.webm'), self.vid_title).run()
        os.remove('video.mp4')
        os.remove('audio.webm')



if __name__=='__main__':
    a = Downloader(link = sys.argv[1])
    a.stream_objects()
    a.downloady()
    a.merge()
```

OKE UPDATE:
Now code looks like that..Second problem is slow downloading mp4 files from YouTube server, i have 10Gb/s internet. Good connection with YT servers, but why so poor downloading ? ? ? :)

```
from pytube import YouTube
import sys
import ffmpeg
import os 
import subprocess

class Downloader(YouTube):

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = YouTube(link)
        self.hq = []


    def stream_objects(self):
        self.best = self.link.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        q = [self.hq.append(x) for x in self.best.all()]
        self.best_vid_itag = str(self.best.all()[1]).split()[1].split('\"')[1]
        self.best_audio_itag = str(self.best.all()[-1]).split()[1].split('\"')[1]

    def downloader(self):
        vid = self.link.streams.get_by_itag(self.best_vid_itag)
        aud = self.link.streams.get_by_itag(self.best_audio_itag)
        print('Donwloading Video file...\n')
        vid.download(filename='video')
        print('Video file downloaded... Now Trying download Audio file..\n')
        aud.download(filename='audio')
        print('Audio file downloaded... Now Trying to merge audio and video files...\n')

    def merger(self):
        lin = str(self.link.title).rstrip()
        lin2 = (lin+'.mp4')
        subprocess.run(f'ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c copy "{lin2}"', shell=True)
        os.remove('video.mp4')
        os.remove('audio.mp4')
        print('Done....\n')

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = Downloader(link = sys.argv[1])
    a.stream_objects()
    a.downloader()
    a.merger()
```

Comment: give tabulation to code.

Comment: @n1tr0xs what u mean ?

Comment: now your code have an empty class. Make class which you need

Comment: @n1tr0xs code works fine, just pasted wrong way :D edited.. fine now

Comment: You should test which of your methods takes the longer. Maybe it's just a matter of your internet connection. Use `datetime.now` in-between  your calls for this :)

Comment: give pls example of link which you give to programm

Comment: it works with any link from yt  exmpl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-KYULAlXFI&list=RDu0q9FQ5S1SY&index=18"

Comment: There are some ugly bits in your code, but nothing that looks like an obvious performances killer. You will have to [profile your code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to really find out where most of the time is spent, but you can bet that most of the execution time will be in downloading the files and merging them.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, most time takes downloading and merging, now i am triing with same formats for exmpl mp4 audio and video and i will see what result

Answer (score 5):

First of all you download a video file and audio file with different encoding

In your case it is mp4 and webm

You should for example download an mp4 video and m4a audio

Or a webm video and a webm audio

Then it comes to ffmpeg, you should pass a parameter “-c copy”

Example for ffmpeg comand line:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -i myaudio.m4a -c copy output.mp4
```

Here is a link to a python project on github use same technique

https://github.com/pyIDM/pyIDM

Check video.py file

Further explanation:

When you use “-c copy” parameter, ffmpeg will just copy the audio track and merge it with video provided that both audio and video has same codec container, this process take less than 2 seconds

Otherwise it will process every frame in video and every bit in audio then convert them to a desired format, which takes very long time

Comment: i am using python-ffmpeg, how should it look in code ? 
ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg.input('video.mp4'), ffmpeg.input('audio.mp4'), self.vid_title).run(), if cli it works, and nice speed

Comment: ffmpeg-python depend on ffmpeg installed in your system, if you just need to merge audio and video just use subprocess example subprocess.run(“ffmpeg -i myvideo -i myaudio -c copy out.mp4”, shell=True)

Comment: Is another way to do this in script without another libs, i am not want use subprocess

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you try to add ffmpeg.filter(“-c”, “copy”) inside your ffmpeg.output() func,

Comment: By the way subprocess is builtin module but ffmpeg is external lib named ffmpeg-python which use subprocess internally